# How to nest two routes in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can you correctly reference a route within a route in ember? I've only seen nesting done with a `resource`. Is this possible to do with just two routes?

I've created a route called `info` nested in the `about` route. But when I try to reference it with `{{#linkTo "info"}}Info{{/linkTo}}` or `{{#linkTo "about.info"}}Info{{/linkTo}}`, I get the error `info route not found` in the console.

App.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about', function(){
    this.route('info');
  });
  this.route('contact');
});
```

hbs:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <p>A little live editor for Ember, written in Ember.</p>

  {{ outlet }} 

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about/info">
  <h2>More Info</h2>
  <p>A little live editor for Ember, written in Ember.</p>
</script>
```

Example reproduced in a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fogozave/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Story:

route's are leaves on a tree.  Leaves don't grow from other leaves.  resource's are branches on a tree.  Branches can have other branches, and they can also have leaves.  The leaf is the end of the road though.

As a context free grammar (something like this):

```
S as application root/resource
Re as resource
Ro as route

S  -> Re | Ro | SS | ε
Re -> Re | Ro | ReRe | ε 
Ro -> ε
```

Reality:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo');
  this.resource('colors', {path:'/colors'}, function(){
    this.route('bar');
    this.resource('color', {path: '/:id'}, function(){
      this.route('baz');
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/fogozave/2/edit

Check out the resource section of this page.  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: what does the `ε` mean in this context?

Comment: ε is used as a terminator.